# when I hover over a div I want it to change the element next to it depending on the number of the nth child that is hovered over

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

[The white line is a `<ul>`, the boxes are div's inside li's, the circles are created using `li:after`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBnV5.png)

I have a ul inside of it are multiple li's and inside of every li a div.

After every `li` there is a circle created using `:after`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background: #37a08e;
  overflow-x: hidden;

}




.line > ul {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.line ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 6px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: white;
}
.line ul li:after{
    content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #49c1a2;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.5s ease-in-out;
  
}

.line ul li div {
  background: #49c1a2;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out, background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.line ul li div:hover {
  background: #49c1a396;
}

.line ul li div a {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.line ul li:nth-child(odd) div {
  left: 40px;
}
.line ul li:nth-child(even) div {
  right: 434px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">...........</a>
            <p>
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis
              aliquid quaerat quam est officia qui enim nulla quibusdam? Hic
              nemo minus nisi doloremque, ducimus inventore eum quisquam aliquam
              libero magnam.
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">
              Coming Soon
            </a>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Voluptatibus magni perspiciatis quaerat dolorum laudantium iste
              sit, maiores molestiae doloremque assumenda?
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">
              Coming Soon
            </a>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Voluptatibus magni perspiciatis quaerat dolorum laudantium iste
              sit, maiores molestiae doloremque assumenda?
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">
              Coming Soon
            </a>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Voluptatibus magni perspiciatis quaerat dolorum laudantium iste
              sit, maiores molestiae doloremque assumenda?
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">
              Coming Soon
            </a>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Voluptatibus magni perspiciatis quaerat dolorum laudantium iste
              sit, maiores molestiae doloremque assumenda?
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">
              Coming Soon
            </a>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Voluptatibus magni perspiciatis quaerat dolorum laudantium iste
              sit, maiores molestiae doloremque assumenda?
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">
              Coming Soon
            </a>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Voluptatibus magni perspiciatis quaerat dolorum laudantium iste
              sit, maiores molestiae doloremque assumenda?
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#">
              Coming Soon
            </a>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Voluptatibus magni perspiciatis quaerat dolorum laudantium iste
              sit, maiores molestiae doloremque assumenda?
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

What I want to do is:
 When I hover over any of the div's the circle border-radius changes according to its nth number, if it is odd the top right corner border-radius changes if it is even the top left border-radius changes.

I think it should should be something like this:

```
.line ul li:nth-child(odd) div:hover /* I don't know what to write here */ {
  border-radius: 50% 0 50% 50%;
}
    .line ul li:nth-child(even) div:hover + /* I don't know what to write here */ {
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: I've added [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to your question, but it doesn't reproduce the issue you are talking about, likely due to missing CSS and perhaps HTML. Please [edit] the question so that it does reproduce the issue.

Comment: There is no issue it's just that I don't know how to select the next element I added a comment to the last code. Sorry, I rolled it back, you made it very confusing, this is a small part of a longer code I can't post the whole thing and there is no reason to.

Comment: The snippets were added to help answerers as well as you... (when added, there's a Copy Snippet to Answer button, which allows answerers to work with your code directly, and show you a working solution).

Comment: I understand but, this is not a complete code as I mentioned before. The snippets won't work correctly.

Comment: Fair enough. Note that I'm not asking for complete code, just a [mre]; enough so that people can give you the right CSS to handle your situation. With no way to try the code and see if it works, I'm not sure you'll get many good answers. Just trying to help you get the best answers, and help others with similar questions that find your question get help as well.

Comment: ok, I've created a reproducible example. I hope it's good enough. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You may want to consider making the circles using `div::after` (or `div::before`), because there's no way to travel back up to the parent with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit to move the circle from the `li` to the `div`, because CSS does not offer a way of traveling back to an ancestor from a descendant. A couple of tweaks to the positioning made it look the same(ish).

Adding the code to change the circle on `:hover` was therefore easy; just add `:hover`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background: #37a08e;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.line>ul {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.line ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 6px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: white;
}

.line ul li div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #49c1a2;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.line ul li div {
  background: #49c1a2;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out, background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.line ul li div:hover {
  background: #49c1a396;
}

.line ul li div a {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.line ul li:nth-child(odd) div {
  left: 40px;
}

.line ul li:nth-child(odd) div::after {
  left: -37px;
}

.line ul li:nth-child(even) div {
  right: 434px;
}

.line ul li:nth-child(even) div::after {
  left: 437px;
}

.line ul li:nth-child(odd) div:hover::after {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.line ul li:nth-child(even) div:hover::after {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">...........</a>
        <p>
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis aliquid quaerat quam est officia qui enim nulla quibusdam? Hic nemo minus nisi doloremque, ducimus inventore eum quisquam aliquam libero magnam.
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
              Coming Soon
            </a>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus magni perspiciatis quaerat dolorum laudantium iste sit, maiores molestiae doloremque assumenda?
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
              Coming Soon
            </a>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus magni perspiciatis quaerat dolorum laudantium iste sit, maiores molestiae doloremque assumenda?
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
              Coming Soon
            </a>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus magni perspiciatis quaerat dolorum laudantium iste sit, maiores molestiae doloremque assumenda?
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
              Coming Soon
            </a>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus magni perspiciatis quaerat dolorum laudantium iste sit, maiores molestiae doloremque assumenda?
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
              Coming Soon
            </a>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus magni perspiciatis quaerat dolorum laudantium iste sit, maiores molestiae doloremque assumenda?
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
              Coming Soon
            </a>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus magni perspiciatis quaerat dolorum laudantium iste sit, maiores molestiae doloremque assumenda?
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
              Coming Soon
            </a>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus magni perspiciatis quaerat dolorum laudantium iste sit, maiores molestiae doloremque assumenda?
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```